# How to access to oplog MongoDB (MMS replica set)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have a MongoDB replica set with [MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com). I created a user with all privileges (all available on MMS) but I can't access to the local db and/or oplog colecction. TRACE:

```
mydatabse-r1:PRIMARY> use local
switched to db local
mydatabse-r1:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find().pretty();
error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on local.oplog.rs", "code" : 13 }
```

I need connect my Meteor app and another apps with Node.js to the oplog but I cannot access it.

**Why?**
Because I'm working on a script with Node.js to create a queue based on the oplog. This is possible, I tested on MongoHQ and MongoLab successfully, but now I need run this in my MMS production replica set with MMS without create a custom MongoDB replica set.

Comment: Please describe why you have to access the oplog and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this link](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-mongodb-replica-set-for-oplog-tailing)

Basically, from mongo 2.6 you need to create a user and grant access to the oplog (as well as accessing the DB using the right credentials)

Something like:

```
db.runCommand({ createRole: "oplogger", 
               privileges: [{ resource: { db: 'local', collection: 'oplog.rs'},
                               actions: ['find']}, ],
               roles: [{role: 'read', db: 'local'}] })
```

Full procedure [here](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-mongodb-replica-set-for-oplog-tailing)