# MMS MongoDB OpLog user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have created MongoDB deployment (replica set) using MMS Portal. I have enabled authentication in MMS portal,  so that DB can be only accessed by providing credentials.

In MMS portal I don't find any option to assign oplog permission to user.

So, how can I create User with OpLog permission?

**Background**

Before posting this question I have searched for for the same, and found following link.

[How to access to oplog MongoDB (MMS replica set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112250/how-to-access-to-oplog-mongodb-mms-replica-set)

Solution in above link is to create roles. But am not sure about this approach because, in MMS portal I can see many build-in roles but in admin database there is no `system.roles` collection!

**INFO** MongoDB version is 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I added user with oplog access for MongoDB Replication set deployed via MMS.

In MMS Portal

1. Click `Deployment -> MongoDB Users` menu.
2. Click `ADD USERS` button.
3. In the form type database as `admin`, type preferred `username` & `password`, in roles enter `root@admin` (You can choose other roles as well which has create users privilege)

Now we have to login via mongo console.

```
mongo <domain.name>:<port>/admin -u <just_created_user> -p
```

Once inside mongo console type following command to create user with access to oplog

```
db.createUser({user: "oplogUser", pwd: "PASSWORD", roles: [{role: "read", db: "local"}]})
```

Now we can access oplog using following URL

```
mongodb://oplogUser:PASSWORD@<domain.name>:<port>/local?authSource=admin
```