# ElasticSearch with MongoDB hosted externally and python

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to use mongo-connector to connect my MongoDB hosted on mongolab and ElasticSearch running locally on a virtual machine. However, I am getting this error:

> OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on
>   local.oplog.rs

Is there a way to connect this externally hosted db using mongo-connector?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112250/how-to-access-to-oplog-mongodb-mms-replica-set

Comment: I already checked that link, not sure how this will work for mongolab specifically. Have you had experience using externally hosted database with mongo-connector